# How to express modalities in lambda calculus - are some extensions required?

Tags: formal-grammars, lambda-calculus, semantics, natural-language-processing, modal-logic

Lambda calculus can be used for encoding semantics of natural language, e.g. http://yoavartzi.com/tutorial/ contains full details about semantic parsing of natural language: converting natural language texts into lambda expressions - Cornell Semantic Parsing Framework is used https://github.com/cornell-lic/spf.

My question is - **how to express modalities in lambda calculus - are some extensions required?** E.g. usual classical modal logics can express beliefs/duties-permissions/knowledge and other kind of modalities. Relational (Kripke) semantics is used for modal logics. So - how can we extend of combine lambda calculus to express modalities?

There is idea to express modalities as just another kind of predicates https://www.amazon.co.uk/Toward-Predicate-Approaches-Modality-Trends-ebook/dp/B016XM48V0 but are there some alternatives, more "natrual" ways to introduce modalities in lambda calculus? Full handling of natural language certainly requires this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Are extensions required? Not really. You can take an axiomatic description of a modal logic and simply provide a "primitive" lambda term for each. The modal operators would become type constructors. Haskell's `IO` monad can be viewed this way. Coherence conditions like the monad laws would provide some conversions between terms.

A different approach, which does involve extending the lambda calculus, is described in Frank Pfenning's and Rowan Davies' [A Judgmental Reconstruction of Modal Logic](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~fp/papers/mscs00.pdf).  Note, this is for an *intuitionistic* modal logic. This involves changing the context, or specifically, having multiple contexts to include hypothetically valid propositions. You get rules like:$$
\frac{\Delta;\cdot\vdash M : A}{\Delta;\Gamma\vdash\mathsf{box}\ M:\square A}\qquad\frac{\Delta;\Gamma\vdash M:\square A\quad\Delta,u::A;\Gamma\vdash N:B}{\Delta;\Gamma\vdash\mathsf{let\ box}\ u=M\ \mathsf{in}\ N : B}$$
You should read the $\mathsf{let\ box}\ u = M\ \mathsf{in}\dots$ as pattern matching/a destructuring bind against $M$.

We have:$$
(\lambda m.\mathsf{let\ box}\ u= m\ \mathsf{in}\ u) : \square A \to A \\
(\lambda f.\lambda x.\mathsf{let\ box}\ f'=f\ \mathsf{in\ let\ box}\ x'=x\ \mathsf{in\ box}\ (f'x')) : \square(A\to B)\to\square A\to\square B \\
(\lambda m.\mathsf{let\ box}\ u=m\ \mathsf{in\ box}\ (\mathsf{box}\ u)) : \square A \to \square \square A$$
Handling possibility as opposed to or in addition to necessity requires a bit more cleverness.